# Microsoft.Identity.Web - SignOut http error 404

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am getting the error message as shown on screenshot when attempting to sign out from my Azure B2C registered application. The Microsoft.Identity.Web nugget is up to date (1.18). I have also amended the _loginpartial.cshtml to reflect asp-area as "MicrosoftIdentity" from "AzureAD" as follows Sign out. In the appsettings.json, I have also setup "SignedOutCallbackPath": as either "/signout-callback-oidc" and "/signout-oidc" unsuccessfully. Same applies to the Front-channel logout URL in the app registration settings in Azure. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the issue. I had not changed the asp-area="AzureAD"  value to asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" against the sign out button I was invoking.